# jQuery library to autopopulate multiple fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple textboxes with set character limits that together make up a code.  There is value in the boxes being separated for a variety of reasons. I want to be able to paste a complete code in the first textbox and have it automatically populate all the textboxes. Is there a way to do this in javascript or a jquery library for this case?

Currently I'm using jQuery autotab on each textbox and I'd prefer to keep that functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9DDvQ/)**

Use the onpaste event to capture the data from the user's clipboard. Then take that data and produce an array appropriate for your inputs. Then set those values using .val()

**JS**

```
$(function(){

    // get first input element
    pastable = document.getElementById('pastable');          
    // listen for the user to paste
    pastable.onpaste = function(e){
        // retrieve paste data as an array split to each 3 characters (3 dots below in regex)
        var inputArray = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain').match(/.../g);
        // loop over input fields
        $('input').each(function(i){
             // place data from paste
             $(this).val(inputArray[i]);                
        });
    };

});​
```

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' id="pastable" maxlength="3"/>
<input type='text' maxlength="3" />
<input type='text' maxlength="3" />​
```

Comment: I just noticed that this only works in Chrome.  Is there a solution that works in firefox and ie9+?  (Your jsfiddle only works in chrome too)

Comment: hmm I didn't realize. That really sucks. Give me a day and I will think of an alternative. I am genuinely interested in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this in JS. I don't know about a library to do it for you through. Shooting from the hip here but maybe something like this:

**Example HTML**

```
<input type='text' data-auto-pop='true' data-group='1' data-char-limit='3'/>
<input type='text' data-auto-pop='true' data-group='1' data-char-limit='3'/>
<input type='text' data-auto-pop='true' data-group='1' data-char-limit='4'/>
```

**Example JS**

```
$("input[data-auto-pop='true']").change(function () {
  var $this = $(this), val = $this.val();
  if ($this.data("char-limit") > val.length) {
    return;
  } else {
    var setVal = function() {
      $this.val(val.slice(0, $this.data("char-limit"));
      val = val.slice($this.data("char-limit"));
    };
    setVal();
    while ($this.closest("input[data-group='"+$this.data("group")+"']") && val.length > 0) {
      $this = $this.closest("input[data-group='"+$this.data("group")+"']");
      setVal();
    }
  }
}
```

Probably has some mistakes in it but you should get the idea.